# Firebase complex query pricing

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a question of firebase pricing system on complex query.
I'm aware of that if I make a query with condition, the result that matches the condition will be counted. Is it still valid if I add sorting condition?

For example

```
documentRef.where('something', isLessThan : condition)
.orderBy('something')
.limit(1).get()
```

if I query and get the only one document sorted by certain condition then is it only 1 read count? or it counts every matches of 'where' condition and then one more count of limit?

Comment: I'd assume that it would stop the query once it gets your single result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only pay for the number of documents you actually get in your app.  A `limit(1)` means only 1 document is received.  It doesn't matter at all how complex your query is.

Answer (score 1):

You pay for the number of documents that are retrieved - not for the number of documents that need to be considered.

The reason for this is that Firestore does all operations before that on indexes, so it doesn't actually have to look at your documents to order them (although the `something` field will need to be in an index).